# Remove all NON-ASCII characters from multiple files in a directory using terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, directory, ascii

I have multiple .fa files in a directory, all of which have non ASCII characters. I've searched the StackOverFlow answers to similar questions but nothing is quite what I need.

I want to be able to give a command in Linux terminal that will rewrite all the files in the directory and save the removal of the non-ASCII characters.

I've tried

```
for file in * do perl -pi 's/[^[ascii:]]//g' *; done

for file in *; do sed -e 's/[\[\]()-+;:,.//'; done

filelist=`ls` for file in $filelist do sed -e 's/[\[\]();:.,+-//g' {$file}

for file in `ls` do sed -e 's/[\[\]();:.,+-//g'; done
```

All with various errors. Thus, I must be missing something in the code syntax.

Note:
*The .fa file is similar to a txt file and can be opened within the terminal or any kind of texteditor, so its not the file composition.

Cheers.

Comment: your loops are specifying a variable name that you never use. `for file in * ; do perl -pi 's/[^[ascii:]]//g' "$file"; done` might work. Other syntax craziness. Try checking your code at https://shellcheck.net . Also, .... `filelist=\`ls\`` constructs can lead to problems if your file names have spaces embedded in them. Good luck.

Comment: the ^ascii portion seems to be the issue within this suggestion. Any ideas on how to not use perl

Comment: now I notice there is another syntax problem. You need to learn how to carefully read the documentation. you need `/[^[:ascii:]]//g'` (I think ;-))  (note the "opening" colon before `ascii`). Good luck.

Comment: This does not work. With or without the additional : 
Still trying to find a way to not use perl.

Comment: ok, try that in `sed`. Does your `sed` support the `-i` (inplace) option? test with `sed -i -n 'p' testFile` should leave the file unchanged (but re-write it, and change the date/timestame on the `ls -l` listing. So (after testing that gives you a clean copy of `testFile` (work only on a file you can afford to lose!) ) , try `for file in * ; do sed -i 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g' "$file"; done` . Will help you to understand what/how `sed` is working to read thru [Grymoire's Sed Tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) .If still trouble, reply with output of `sed --version ; uname -srv`. Good Luck!

Comment: Also, wondering if this a mis-match on OS file formats. run `cat -vet oneFileNotWorking | head -5` . If you see `^M$` at the end of each line, then convert files from Windows format to *nix, with `dos2unix allFiles*` . Good luck.

Comment: And finally, (what should have been the first Q (on my part, doah!) ),please give some examples of what  you mean by non-ascii chars? If you mean UTF-8/16 sort of things like the umlat, diacritical marks on vowels (and others), etc, you'll probably need to search for clues on how to pre-clean you files with other utilities.I'm thinking of `iconv`. Good luck.